# Mac Os Visual Studio Code C++ Opengl Glad Glew

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Link Project
https://github.com/nio74/templateGLad

Good day, I try Run Opengl app with glew and glad in Visual Studio Code(I wanted to use this Ide because it is multi platform but if you have any good suggestions it is welcome), but have this error:

```
 > Executing task: C/C++: clang++ build active file <

Starting build...
Build finished with error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gladLoadGLLoader", referenced from:
      _main in HelloWorld-22d65f.o
```

My tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/HelloWorld.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "-I", "${workspaceFolder}/include/",
                //"${workspaceFolder}/glad.c",
                "-lglfw",
                "-lglew"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why is the `glad.c` file commented out in your build script? You should also just invest some time in a decent build system instead of the simplistic one in VSC.

Comment: I also tried not to comment it but it tells me that I cannot compile in c:                   
Build finished with error:

clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
ld: can't open output file for writing: /Users/paolomazzon/Desktop/Progettic++/OPENGL/prova1, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

Comment: So you need to compile glad.c separately into a static library (.a file) first and pass *that* in your tasks.json. Alternatively, any decent build system (like CMake) will take care of that for you. Finally: you need to link with EITHER glew OR glad, not both.

Comment: why do you commit all that generated stuff, only `HelloWorld.cpp` is made by you

Comment: -Botje I try to make a library staticI'll have to study how to do it, by chance you have a template to understand how it's done '

Comment: -rioV8  "${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp" So OK?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at https://github.com/Polytonic/Glitter , which has all the build system stuff preconfigured to use GLAD+GLFW

Comment: Thanks I will watch it

Answer (score 0):

Updating, doing various research I managed to make it work, but I have some things to understand:

I can't understand the variables in tasks.Json

```
(

"--include-directory = include /",
"--include-directory = build /",
"--include = include / glad.c",
```

)

I tried to replace them with those suggested by the official guide (

```
"$ {workspaceFolder} / include",
"$ {workspaceFolder} / build",
"$ {fileDirname} /include/glad.c",
```

)
but they don't work.

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "HelloWorld",
            "type": "che",
            "command": "clang++",
            "args": [
            
                
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-lglfw",
                "-lglew",
                "--include-directory=include/",
                "--include-directory=build/",
                "--include=include/glad.c",
                //"${workspaceFolder}/include",
                //"${workspaceFolder}/build",
                //"${fileDirname}/include/glad.c",
                
                "-framework",
                "OpenGL",
                "-framework",
                "IOKit",
                "-framework",
                "Cocoa",
                "src/helloworld.cpp",
                "-o",
                "build/helloworld",
                "--debug"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]

}
```

launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
               
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "HelloWorld",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/helloworld",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": true,
                "MIMode": "lldb",
                
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x86",
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-lglfw",
                "-lglew"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Git:

https://github.com/nio74/templateGLad

Comment: I auto answer by myself it can be useful for someone, just read the clang build specs are its commands;)